# Should you await Navigator calls in buttons

Tags: flutter

Considering that `Navigator.of(context).push()` returns a `Future<void>`, is it a good idea to be `await`ing them inside of buttons?

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
  onPressed: () => AutoRouter.of(context).push(
    SearchPageRoute(),
  ),
)

// -->

IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
  onPressed: () async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      SearchPageRoute(),
    );
  },
)
```

Would it make any difference on a practical level? I'm asking because I recently made a `AsyncButtonBuilder` that handles the loading state and disabled state of buttons but am curious if Navigation operations would ever have the latency required to even show a loading indicator.

For example, is this next piece of code pointless considering Navigator is almost synchronous -- at least as it appears to me?

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  var isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Icon(Icons.search),
      onPressed: isLoading
          ? null
          : () async {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = true;
              });
              await Navigator.of(context).push(SearchPageRoute());
              if (mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              }
            },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why they have a future callback is because you can pass results back to the page where you push from. A good example will be pushing a dialog and waiting for a response from the user. This is where you use `await` to wait for the user input, then from what response the user selected it will return back to the first screen where you `pushed` it.

**TLDR:** if you don't need to wait for a response from a screen you don't need to include `await`.